# Why we can't use $_POST instead of $_FILES to access the uploaded file in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

When I am trying to access the uploaded file by using `$_POST` then I didn't get any info but if I use `$_FILES` the I will get all uploaded file related stuff.

Why we can't use `$_POST` instead of `$_FILES`?

Comment: There isn't really answer for this except that it is how PHP was designed, many years ago. That's just how it works - the $_POST superglobal holds post field data, $_FILES holds file input metadata. They could have made different choices 20+ years ago, but did not.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski but we must know the reason behind this as we are devlopers

Comment: @AmolKhaire why *must* we?

Comment: I disagree that we must know the reason. If you want to know the reason, Rasmus might reply to your email inquiry.  I am personally no more concerned with this reason than I am with why a C `for` loop has the syntax it has.

Answer (score 2):

This is ***a language design decision*** which was made by the creators of PHP long ago. You could ask the creator of PHP Rasmus Lerdorf (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf).

However there are some good reasons I can think about to seperate `$_POST` and `$_FILES`.

From the docs:

> The global $_FILES will contain all the uploaded file information. [...]
>   Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary
>   directory, unless another location has been given with the
>   upload_tmp_dir directive in php.ini. The server's default directory
>   can be changed by setting the environment variable TMPDIR in the
>   environment in which PHP runs. Setting it using putenv() from within a
>   PHP script will not work. This environment variable can also be used
>   to make sure that other operations are working on uploaded files, as
>   well.

The `$_FILES` array contains info like name, type, size, temporary name, error information, temporary location and so on. So for a file a lot of information is required and it has seperate data stored in some temporary place.

The `$_POST` array just contains submitted text strings basically. Therefore my guess it that the design decision was made just because it is useful to have this variables clearly seperated.